# increase items in shopping cart using rails and redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having trouble increasing the quantity of items in the cart. It will only add one, then the it switches to the 'remove' button. Is there some way I can reconfigure this so I can add more than one of each item?

carts_controller.rb

```
def add
  $redis.sadd current_user_cart, params[:item_id]
  render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
end
```

carts.coffee

```
$(window).load ->
  $('a[data-target]').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $this = $(this)
    if $this.data('target') == 'Add to'
      url = $this.data('addurl')
      new_target = "Remove from"
    else
      url = $this.data('removeurl')
      new_target = "Add to"
    $.ajax url: url, type: 'put', success: (data) ->
      $('.cart-count').html(data)
      $this.find('span').html(new_target)
      $this.data('target', new_target)


  $('#mycart .remove').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $this = $(this).closest('a')
    url = $this.data('targeturl')
    $.ajax url: url, type: 'put', success: (data) ->
      $('.cart-count').html(data)
      $this.closest('.cart-item').slideUp()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out on my own. The items are now being saved to an array, now more than one can be added to the cart. The 'add to' button is also no longer toggling back and forth between 'add to' and 'remove from'. The 'remove' button is now separate.

```
  def show
   cart_ids = $redis.lrange current_user_cart, -100, 100
   @cart_items = Item.find(cart_ids)
  end

 def add
  $redis.lpush current_user_cart, params[:item_id]
  render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
 end

 def remove
  $redis.lrem current_user_cart, 1, params[:item_id]
  render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
 end
```